# Using a matrix as initial condition in scipy.integrate.solve_ivp

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I would like to pass a matrix as initial condition for `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`.

With odeInt this was possible by flattening the matrix as:

`Result = odeint(myfunction, myMatrix.ravel(),myTimeVector )`

Inside the function `myFunction`, the matrix is reshaped into a 3x3 matrix for some calculations.

If I try to use `solve_ivp(myfunction, myTimeVector,myMatrix.ravel() )`, I get the following error:
`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (3,3)`
because it only passes the first element of the array, instead of the whole array. Is it possible pass the matrix as initial condition as was with`odeint`?

Best Regards

Comment: What do the docs say?

Comment: From odeint, y0 is the Initial condition on y (can be a vector). From solve_ipv y0 is the Initial state. For problems in the complex domain, pass y0 with a complex data type (even if the initial value is purely real).

Comment: Did you switch the order of arguments? `odeint` by default takes `f(y,t)` while `solve_ivp` takes `f(t,y)`. You can also use the latter with `odeint` and the option `tfirst=True`.

Comment: FYI: [`odeintw`](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/odeintw) provides a wrapper of `odeint` that allows it to handle 2-d arrays.  It is also on PyPi at https://pypi.org/project/odeintw/

Answer (score 1):

Well... Solved it in the following manner:

Changed the entries in `myFunction(y,t)` to  `myFunction(t,y)`

`Result=solve_ivp(myfunction, (myTimeVector[0], myTimeVector[-1]), myMatrix.ravel(), t_eval=myTimeVector)`

Comment: You can avoid having two versions with the arguments switched by always defining the function as `myFunction(t, y)` and passing the argument `tfirst=True` to [`odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html).